# How map looks in JSON Format?

Tags: java, json, dictionary, postman

There is

```
Map<UUID, Set<UUID> map
```

Can someone give an example how it will be looked in JSON format

Comment: Something like `{"$UUID1":["$UUID2","$UUID3","$UUID4"...],...}` but why not trying to check it yourself?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Easiest way to check is to use GSON library. Convert your map to `JsonObject` and then print it.